# Error Send email from googlesheet stops for loop with invalid email. How to skip

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a googlescript that sends emails. It is working well but it seems to completely stop when it hits an invalid email. There's one field that is a manually inputted email address that is periodically incorrect. 10 emails failed because the script stopped at one row because of invalid email and didn't move forward. I don't write in javascript/googlescript so this has been a very challenging project for me. I appreciate any help.

I'll assume that I need to add something that skips a row if the email is invalid. What do I need to change in my script? Is there a way to push back to the submitter if he/she entered an invalid email address (the script is triggered via form submit)? I'm open to alternatives and recommendations if there are best practices.

```
var url_monitoreo_desarrollos='https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/AAAAofT51oM/messages?key=AIzaSyDdI0hCZtE6vySjMm-WEfRq3CPzqKqqsHI&token=oQMnPmnOTvX83JwYMz_Jprgv-xGu9eD9J_WV0rr3e70%3D';

function main_emailReminderAlert() {
  try{
    // getting data from spreadsheet    
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('BASE');
    var startRow = 2; // Ignore the cloumn hedings and freezed rows
    var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1; // Get the last number of row that has content with excluding header rows
    var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
    // Get the last number of column that has content.
    //Get data range dynamically
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, numColumns);
    var data = dataRange.getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
      var row = data[i];
      var fecha_act = new Date(), // fecha actual
      fecha_venc = row[12] // fecha de vencimiento de la licencia 
      numero = row[0]
      config = row[11]
      est_aviso1=row[17]
      est_aviso2=row[18]
      est_aviso3=row[19]
      est_aviso4=row[20]
      dest_1=row[21],
      dest_2=row[22],
      webhook =row[23]
    
      var lic_detalles = 
        {
          numero:row[0],
          pais:row[1],
          marca:row[2],
          tecnologia: row[3],
          nombre_equipo:row[4],
          cliente:row[5],
          ip:row[6],
          modelo:row[7],
          serial_number:row[8],
          licencia:row[9],
          sm:row[10],
          config:row[11],
          est_aviso1:row[17],
          est_aviso2:row[18],
          est_aviso3:row[19],
          est_aviso4:row[20],
          dest_1:row[21],
          dest_2:row[22],
          webhook:row[23],
          
        };

      //Remove the time part from the date
      var t2 = new Date(fecha_venc);
      t2.setHours(0,0,0,0);
      var t1 = new Date(fecha_act);
      t1.setHours(0,0,0,0);

      //Calcula la diferencia en ms
      var diferencia_ms = (t2.getTime() - t1.getTime());
      // 24*3600*1000 is milliseconds in a day
      var dias_rest = (diferencia_ms/(24*3600*1000));
    
      //
      lic_detalles.dias_rest = dias_rest;
      lic_detalles.numero=numero;
      lic_detalles.config=config;
      lic_detalles.est_aviso1=est_aviso1;
      lic_detalles.est_aviso2=est_aviso2;
      lic_detalles.est_aviso3=est_aviso3;
      lic_detalles.est_aviso4=est_aviso4;
      lic_detalles.webhook=webhook;

      if(config == "Activado"  ) {
     
        if(dias_rest>=0 && dias_rest<=5  && est_aviso4==false ) {

          console.log("LA LICENCIA DE "+lic_detalles.cliente+" VENCE EN 5 DIAS");
          sendEmail(lic_detalles);
          notificaAlerta(lic_detalles);
          sheet.getRange(numero+1, 17).setValue(fecha_act);
          sheet.getRange(numero+1, 21).setValue(true);
      
        }
        else  if(dias_rest>=6 && dias_rest<=15   && est_aviso3==false){

          console.log("LA LICENCIA DE "+lic_detalles.cliente+" VENCE EN 15 DIAS ");
          sendEmail(lic_detalles);
          notificaAlerta(lic_detalles);
          sheet.getRange(numero+1, 16).setValue(fecha_act);
          sheet.getRange(numero+1, 20).setValue(true);
  
        }
   
    
        else  if (dias_rest>=16 && dias_rest<= 30  && est_aviso2== false  ) {

          console.log("LA LICENCIA DE "+lic_detalles.cliente+" VENCE EN 30 DIAS");
          sendEmail(lic_detalles);
          notificaAlerta(lic_detalles);
          sheet.getRange(numero+1, 15).setValue(fecha_act);
          sheet.getRange(numero+1,19).setValue(true);

        }
   
        else if (dias_rest >= 31 && dias_rest <= 60  && est_aviso1== false) {

          console.log("LA LICENCIA DE "+lic_detalles.cliente+" VENCE EN 60 DIAS");
          sendEmail(lic_detalles);
          notificaAlerta(lic_detalles);
          sheet.getRange(numero+1, 14).setValue(fecha_act);
          sheet.getRange(numero+1, 18).setValue(true);
        }
      }
    }
  }catch(e){
    var tiempo = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    var log=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('LOG')
    log.appendRow([tiempo, e]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    notificaMonitoreo(e,url_monitoreo_desarrollos);
  }
}

function sendEmail(lic_detalles){
    //Get the html email template
    var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile   ('EmailTemplate');   templ.lic_detalles = lic_detalles;
    var messagemail = templ.evaluate().getContent();
    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: lic_detalles.dest_1+","+lic_detalles.dest_2,
    cc:lic_detalles.dest_1+","+lic_detalles.dest_2,
    subject: lic_detalles.cliente+" SU LICENCIA VENCE EN " + lic_detalles.dias_rest + " DIAS ",
    htmlBody: messagemail   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply enclose your code in `sendEmail` in a `try{} catch() {}` block so if an error occurs it will simply return.  I don't make any guarantee about the rest of our code.

```
function sendEmail(lic_detalles){
  try {
    //Get the html email template
    var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile   ('EmailTemplate');   templ.lic_detalles = lic_detalles;
    var messagemail = templ.evaluate().getContent();
    MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: lic_detalles.dest_1+","+lic_detalles.dest_2,
    cc:lic_detalles.dest_1+","+lic_detalles.dest_2,
    subject: lic_detalles.cliente+" SU LICENCIA VENCE EN " + lic_detalles.dias_rest + " DIAS ",
    htmlBody: messagemail   });
  }
  catch(err) {
    return;
  }
}
```